Why sometime the out_features in Linear layer is higher than in_features?
I understand that in the out_features in Linear often lower than the in_features to get more meaningful feature but some time I see the out_features is higher than the in_features, sometimes it's equal.
For example, like the architecture below in swin transformer v2 in pytorch:
Sequential(
      (0): SwinTransformerBlockV2(
        (norm1): LayerNorm((768,), eps=1e-05, elementwise_affine=True)
        (attn): ShiftedWindowAttentionV2(
          (qkv): Linear(in_features=768, out_features=2304, bias=True) #Higher
          (proj): Linear(in_features=768, out_features=768, bias=True) #Equal
          (cpb_mlp): Sequential(
            (0): Linear(in_features=2, out_features=512, bias=True)
            (1): ReLU(inplace=True)
            (2): Linear(in_features=512, out_features=24, bias=False) # Lower
          )

I want to ask:

What are the purposes by having higher, equal, lower out_features in the network?
Can you provide me some papers about this matter and network architetures having this?

I'm just start learning about deep learning and AI, if you can provide some course about building network, it will be great help.
Thank you so much.

You are asking questions about non-programming issues, then asking for recommendations, both are off-topic and frowned upon in Stack Overflow.

Your question is tangled with 2 meanings, the transformer block and Linear block. It could be explained with 2 branches:

What are the purposes by having higher, equal, lower out_features in the network?


In image transformers, qkv(query, key value) is designed to get the correlations of input patches. out_features=2304 is 3 multiples of in_features=768. They are divided with 3 elements of qkv, which can be found on foward() function on implements. Hope to explore the reference script from __init__() to forward() and understand transformer paper thoroughly.
In Linear block, building a block with parameters in_features and out_features is heuristic. The number of features in Linear block is dimension of function you hypothesis. We encode the input feature that could be represented in lower-dimension(the bottleneck of the network), and decode it what we want solve.


Can you provide me some papers about this matter and network architectures having this?


I hope to read articles of linear regression before learning about deep learning, following fundamental theory of linear algebra. Your learning curve can be followed with: linear regression, classification -> multi layer perceptron(same as Linear in Pytorch) -> convolution block -> transformers -> image transformers(Swin transformer on post)."


Thank you for your answer. I noticed in the VGG19, that the first two of the three last FC layers have the same 4096 channel. Does having this help anything to the networks? Cause I have done some experiments on the last layers of my custom network by having higher out_features than in_feature, followed by the equal, then followed with lower for the output. It gives better results sometimes.

@luânnguyễn As mensioned in second phrase of first question, the out_features of linear block is very heuristic. Sometimes it highly depends on the learning rate proportional to the number of dimensions(gradient vanishing and exploding). There also  is an network architecture search(NAS) method for your unsolved question. Note again, it is very heuristic, varying with dataset, network size, optimizer,  loss function, and etc, so defined as a hyper-paramater.
